# Wildfly custom login module failed to load properties file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am new to Java EE and Wildfly, now i am learning how to implement a custom login module for my application. I follow from this tutorial http://www.radcortez.com/custom-principal-and-loginmodule-for-wildfly/. But when i deploy my app to wildfly server ( 8.2.0.Final) and try to login it always print out exception on the console

```
[org.jboss.security] (default task-1) PBOX000287: Failed to open properties file from URL: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Volumes/Data/Windows/Documents/Ebook/Java/JavaEE/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/configuration/users.properties
```

I do have the users.properties file in the above directory. I found some discussion talking about this but no one gives a final solution. Please help me, thank you very much. Here is my other configurations

```
<security-domain name="token-login-module" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.ege.TokenLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the exception PicketBox is trying to parse your configured path as an URL. Your path doesn't contain a protocol, which is exactly what the exception message tells you. Try prefixing your path with the correct protocol, which is most probably:

```
file://
```

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2859201

Check this link for error.

**Resolution**
This message can be safely ignored, it's the UsersRoles login module checking for all it's options. If the defaultUsersProperties or defaultRolesProperties aren't defined it will write that message in the log when org.jboss.security is set to DEBUG or TRACE.